# Php mail() send data from db with table

Tags: php, mysql, email, while-loop

i want to send mail with data from database and using php mail() this is my code :

```
<?php
class emailKoala{
  public function __construct()
  {
  }
public function kirimEmailDaftar($email,$name,$order_id,$order_hargatotal){
    include "../config.php";
    $sqlbank="SELECT * FROM `bank`";
    $querybank=mysql_query($sqlbank);

    $to      = "$email";
    $subject = "order information!";
    $message = 'thanks :) this is bank account
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Bank</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>'.while($arraybank=mysql_fetch_array($querybank)){
.'<tr>
<td>'.$arraybank['bank'].'</td>
<td>'.$arraybank['norek'].'</td>
<td>'.$arraybank['ket'] .'</td>
</tr>'.}.
'id order :'.$order_id.',shop again! ';

    $headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".
                'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n".
                'From: shoesshe <cs@shoesshe.com>' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: shoesshe <cs@shoesshe.com>' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

  }
}
```

i was try like that but

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE in /model/email.php on
>   line 34

i was try before using text only and thats work, i just want to send data to that mail with table using while..

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your message string. You can't put a while in there.
This will work:

```
$message = 'thanks :) this is bank account
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Bank</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>';
while($arraybank=mysql_fetch_array($querybank)){
$message .='
<tr>
<td>'.$arraybank['bank'].'</td>
<td>'.$arraybank['norek'].'</td>
<td>'.$arraybank['ket'] .'</td>
</tr>';
}

$message .= 'id order :'.$order_id.',shop again! ';
```

As you can see, the while will add more text to your string in each loop. You were concatenating the while before, and it would not work.